# Configure scaladoc to include extension methods

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scaladoc, enrich-my-library

Can I configure scaladoc to include methods from implicit conversions by specifying the implicit conversion?

E.g. given

```
trait Foo

object Operations {
  implicit class FooOps(val f: Foo) extends AnyVal {
    def bar = 33
  }
}
```

Can I make scaladoc include extension method `bar` in the documentation of `Foo`?

Answer (score 1):

It appears so (I've not tried it yet):

```
% scladoc -help
Usage: scaladoc <options> <source files>
where possible scaladoc options include:
  ...
  -implicits                    Document members inherited by implicit conversions.
  -implicits-hide:<implicit(s)> Hide the members inherited by the given comma separated, fully qualified implicit conversions. Add dot (.) to include default conversions.
  -implicits-show-all           Show members inherited by implicit conversions that are impossible in the default scope. (for example conversions that require Numeric[String] to be in scope)
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks. This does work for implicit conversions which are in default scope, e.g. inside the package object in which `Foo` resides. However, it doesn't include any enrichments which must be imported, like `Operations` in the example. I don't know if there are further tricks to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know either, but probably not?

Comment: did you try adding an `import Operations._` above where `trait Foo` is defined? that might trick scaladoc tool into including the implicit method